# Exact value of argv[0] when running C executable

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have the following C file which I compile to an executable `test`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // do some computation
}
```

Suppose that I call this binary from the command line with the call `./test foo`. At that point, is the value of `argv[0]` equal to `"foo"`, or is it equal to some address in memory?

Comment: afair argv[0] will be `test` - name of the executable file

Comment: `argv` is a pointer to an array, each element of which is a pointer to an array of characters. In particular, `argv[0]` is a pointer to an array of characters, containing the characters `.`, `/`, `t`, `e`, `s`, `t`, and a NUL byte.

Comment: If `argc > 0`, `argv[0]` will hold the program's name as [@icktoofay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409369/exact-value-of-argv0-when-running-c-executable#comment52686510_32409369) commented.  On _most_ systems, `argc` is at least 1.

Comment: Side note: it's never a good idea to call a program "test", since on UNIXish platform "test" is _already_ the name of a program, see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test). A mistake I made in my noob days, like a lot of people...

Comment: @Lashane, to be exact: `argv[0]` is a *pointer to* a `char`-array containing the program's name `test`.

Answer (score 4):

`argv[0]` will hold the address in a memory of the string "./test". `argv[1]` will hold the address in memory of the string "foo".

A `char*` is a pointer to a single character. You can use that pointer-to-a-character as if it were a string (more easily if the data are NUL-terminated). But it is, at its heart, a pointer to some memory which contains character data.

A `char**` is a pointer to a `char*`. In this case we treat that `char**` as an array of `char*`s. But really it's just a pointer to a memory address which holds a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

The `argc` value and the `argv[]` array of char pointers and the strings the `argv[]` pointers point to, are all in readonly memory.  so do not try to modify them in any way.

`argv[0]` is a char pointer to a string. 
The string contents will be: `"test"`, including a trailing `'\0'`.

`argv[1]` is a char pointer to a string. 
The string contents will be: `"foo"`, including a trailing `'\0'`.

`argv[2]` is a char pointer. 
That pointer will contain `NULL`.

`argc` is a integer. 
That integer will contain 2. 
because the `argc` contains a count of the number of valid pointers in the `argv[]` array 
( the final `NULL` pointer is not counted )

Comment: On Linux, you can overwrite the strings of `argv[]` ; a future `ps`  command would see the updated strings. Updating `argc` to insert a string is much more tricky (next to impossible)